# Add newer version of a package to Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am working with old Linux built with Yocto. I need to update one package in the image. Recipes for the package can be found here: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/.

What is the best way to do it? Should I add a new layer with a newer version of the recipe and the `.patch` files? Does Yocto know which version of the recipe should be used? Recipe file names differ because they have different names (different version suffixes) but in the package I want to be used there is an `.inc` file. Does Yocto know which `.inc` file should be used?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Just copy-paste the recipe to your meta-layer and try to build it.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to make any changes in the standard layers. Instead you can make a custom layer and add the support for newer version there with the patch files.

You can use PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto in your machine file to set the version you want to compile. Or PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto_*your-MACHINE-name* in the local.conf.

While making your custom recipe for kernel, also include the .inc file in same directory. Yocto will first search for .inc file in the recipe directory.